# android - CardView Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview, adt, cardview

I am facing the following exception in eclipse ADT while implementing CardView.

> Exception raised during rendering:
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to
>   android.view.ViewGroup

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have added android-support-v7-cardview.jar and android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar to build path. Android version used to render is 22. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: I assume you have already tried to clean your project and rebuilding?

Comment: Yes i have tired that @user1504495